# How do I publish trading view API with my pine code in my website?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have written the code in pine editor in Trading view. How do I call it via API in my website?

Search this webpage too (https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) but did not getting the single clue for that.

Can somebody please help me in this regards.

Hassan Akhtar